# Creating a Sub Domain on Dreamhost

Tags: httpd.conf, dreamhost, httpd

I am trying to create a sub domain play.mink7.com

i went to Domains and Add Domain and added the Subdomain. 
It created the DNS records.

Now when i go to the website http://play.mink7.com am getting the following error

> Site Temporarily Unavailable We apologize for the inconvenience.
>   Please contact the webmaster/ tech support immediately to have them
>   rectify this.
>
> error id: "bad_httpd_conf"

Any idea how to change this ?

Comment: Every thing is ok for me when I try to reach [your subdomain](http://hurl.it/hurls/add6b7a63f2ef0b7ac747538b1540082737cd6d9/3a233b63ada301d0b07e4766a6e01d168940e101).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said, it's working now. For the actual reason:

[Just wait a little while](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Bad_httpd_conf).
This error comes up on Dreamhost when you make some kinds of edits–in your case see the "DNS changes" heading for a detailed explanation–and they haven't fully resolved yet. If it lasts more than a couple of hours, then you should file a support request, because unfortunately this message is about as specific as "Internal Server Error" and it also comes up in some other cases where something really *is* wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me too:

```
play.mink7.com Coming Soon!

The DreamHost customer who owns play.mink7.com has not yet uploaded their website or has chosen to leave this holding page active.

If you are the owner of this domain, you'll find your login information contained within the emails sent to you when your account was activated. Once logged in, you'll be able to delete this page (quickstart.html) and upload your new site.

Here are some helpful links for getting started:
[etc.]
```

Now you have to just upload your files.